# Security rule strange behaviour?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

allowed access with blank UID

DATA

```
{
  "roles": {
    "admins": {
      "123456789": {
        "name": "Max"
      }
    }
  },
  "meta": {},
  "events": {
    "3423556": {
      },
      "meta": {
      }
    },
  }
}
```

RULES

```
"rules": {
    "events": {
    ".read": "root.child('roles').child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)",
    }
}
```

it returns faile if I'm trying

> Type  read Location   /events/ Data   null Auth   { "provider": "anonymous",
>   "uid": "1" } Admin    false

and true if UID is blank

> Type  read Location   /events/ Data   null Auth   { "provider": "anonymous",
>   "uid": "" } Admin false

Comment: A valid user should *always* have a UID, so you second test case seems invalid to me.

Comment: generally, agree, but security rule must be more secure IMHO

Comment: How did you test this? Because I don't think any provider creates a user with a UID, and I'd actually expect Firebase Authentication to reject those. If you're testing this with the emulator, it could just be a bug there. In general, if you feel you've found a bug, it's best to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with Firebase support.